# WPF error message: Partial declaration must not specify different base classes

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Why do I have this error message for a UserControl:

> Partial declaration of
>   MyNamespace.MyUserControl must not
>   specify different base classes

Just because I inherited from another UserControl class I created in another namespace whereas this other namespace is referenced in the XAML as

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ReferedNamespace;assembly=ReferedNamespace"
```

Comment: can you post more xaml and declaration of your calls

Comment: please notice that there is no space between `assembly` and `;`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Little to go on here, but this usually happens when the code behind and the xaml file do not inherit from the same base class.

Since we do not have all the details concerning your problem,
I'll create a situation that will cause the same exception to be thrown,
this might help you understand your problem.

As an example, just create new WPF application using Visual Studio,
The XAML might look something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" .....>
```

The code behind would then contain something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //Code here
}
```

Note the 'partial' modifier here. It means this class (MainWindow) might
not be defined in a single file but spread out across multiple files,
in this case the XAML (.xaml.cs) and the CS (.cs) files.

Now add a new UserControl to the solution. It will be named UserControl1.

Without making any changes to the XAML, change the code behind for the MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : UserControl1
{
    //Code here
}
```

Now you'll get the exception you questioned about.

Look for something like this in your code, if you still can't find a solution,
please provide more code.

Comment: Hi thanks that was indeed linked to inheritance. I've solved the problem.

Comment: How can we tell the xaml to use `UserControl1` instead of `Window` ??

Answer (score 21):

look to both your .cs and .xaml files at this parts

- in .xaml file :

  ```
  <Window x:Class="BUSsAsDesign.GUI.IGPopUP" > ...... </Window>
  ```
- in .cs file :

  ```
  namespace BUSsAsDesign.GUI
  {
     public partial class IGPopUP : Window
    {

     //code here

    }
  }
  ```
- Now if u wanna change Window to UserControl
- change

  ```
  <Window x:Class="BUSsAsDesign.GUI.IGPopUP" > ....... </Window>
  <!--**becomes**-->
  <UserControl x:Class="BUSsAsDesign.GUI.IGPopUP" > ....... </UserControl>
  ```

---

```
    namespace BUSsAsDesign.GUI
    {
      public partial class IGPopUP : Window
      {

       //code here

      }
    }
    //**becomes**
    namespace BUSsAsDesign.GUI
    {
      public partial class IGPopUP : UserControl
      {

       //code here

       } 
    }
```

- i hope it`s useful :) .

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot, this actually provided the solution for the problem in question!

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add this piece of information. In Visual Studio 2017, There is a bug which I haven't had time to dig into with much depth, but it causes this error. (from the OP)

**Overview:** When declaring a partial class as an x:Class for a resource xaml file, it will cause this error, and after removing the declaration, the error will persist.

To reproduce this bug, (or if you are here because you are getting this error message)

**Step 1:**  Create a new WPF Project.
**Step 2:**  Create a new Resource File
**Step 3:**  Change the resource files name-space to the projects main namespace (remove the bit at the end.)
**Step 4:** In the resource files declaration/header section, add an x:Class declaration specifying your MainWindow (default startup window object) as the Class for that resource file.  (EG:  x:Class=MainWindow)
**Step 5:** Clean/Rebuild Solution
**Step 6:** You should now be getting this error from the OP. So remove the x:Class Declaration from your header on the Resource File, and save/clean/rebuild the project.

If the bug was reproduced, the error should remain, even though you have removed the x:Class declaration from the resource file.

The only solution I could find for this bug, is to **delete** the projects **Bin** folder, and **any other folder with builds in it.**

After deleting them, Clean/Rebuild your project, and the error should be gone.